# charge a 15v Cap with 24v

Tags: capacitor, charging

Can I charge a 15V Cap with a 24V supply, as long as I have the supply disconnect, once the cap reaches 15v ?

I have seen the analogy of comparing the voltage to the max psi of a tank, and if you go over, it will quite literally spill out.  So in this case, it would be like filling a 100 psi tank with a 150 psi source and simply shutting the fill valve when reaching 100 psi.  Should work no?

Thanks for you input in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the concept could work to disconnect the 24V charging supply as long as you had arranged the charging time constant to give sufficient time to detect the voltage over 15V and get the supply disconnected.

What this means is that you would not want to be trying to charge the capacitor with it directly connected to the supply. In that case it would charge so fast that some detector comparator circuit, which might have a 1usec response time and a switch MOSFET which may also have a response time, may not have been able to register the 15V event before the cap was charged farther than 15V.

So use an series R to charge through so that you limit the charge rate giving time for the detect circuit.

You have another choice to make a voltage divider of two resistors that divide 24V down to 15V. Then connect your capacitor across the lower resistor of the divider and it will only charge to 15V.

Comment: With the note that he better understand what he's doing, or he's going to blow up the cap.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - I was already in progress of adding more to my answer. If the OP is trying just use test leads off the 24V supply and note 15V charge on the cap with a multimeter and then hoping that he can remove the lead quick enough - all is lost - the cap likely blows up.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Even worse, Most caps will tolerate the overcharge abuse several dozen of times without showing symptoms. The time until fatal failure degrades from solid 10 to 15 years down to a day though.

Comment: Just go for the voltage divider option, that's by far the most fool-proof way!